# How to remove Ubuntu from my windows 7 64 bit

Tags: 12.04, uninstall

I used the version of ubuntu that allows you to install through windows.  When I start my system it asks me if I want to select Ubuntu or Windows 7.  No problem, but I wanted to dual boot by giving ubuntu 250 gb and keep 2500 gb for my windows.  The only problem is I am afraid that if I install Ubuntu on my machine and use the new partition I created that I will not actually be able to boot into it(because I already have a version installed)

Also, if I just install Ubuntu from an iso will it let me select which system to boot into, or am I better off to leave it how it is now?

Thanks

Comment: 250* gb for windows not 2500

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to keep the version you have now?  The easiest and safest way to accomplish what you have said would be to remove the current version, which you can do via the Windows uninstall.  If you need data on the current version, you could copy the needed data to the Windows partition or an external drive.  Copying your home directory is usually enough, although if you have installed a lot of programs that have configurations, some of this might be stored in the `/etc` directory.

Installing the new version will normally keep the existing Windows, assuming you don't tell it to do something differently.  The default is to keep any existing operating systems, but this can be defeated.  The only thing it will do that is somewhat destructive is to add a boot manager that will replace the normal Windows MBR code.  Once this is done, you don't want to simply delete the Ubuntu partition without first repairing this, which is not hard.

You can read more on the [Ubuntu Help site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)

Comment: I would resize the partition in Windows before attempting to install Ubuntu instead of letting the Ubuntu installer doing the resizing. In the past I had a bad experience with the installer rendinging the windows partition unusable and requiring a full install of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the Windows version (Wubi) first by uninstalling it from Windows like any Windows program. Then you can use the ISO to install your dual-boot system.